# How to get business exception from wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, testing

How can I test for this exception as returned from a WCF call?

I have this error class.

```
[Serializable]
public class PermissionDenied_Error : Exception
{
    public PermissionDenied_Error() : base("You are not approved.") { }
}
```

In my Service, I am throwing it.

```
if (notApproved)
{
    throw new FaultException<PermissionDenied_Error>(new PermissionDenied_Error()
              , new FaultReason("Permissions Denied!"));
}
```

In my test, I am expecting it.

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FaultException<PermissionDenied_Error>))]
```

Current result is:

```
Expected: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[PermissionDenied_Error
    , Project.API, Version=1.0.4318.24332, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
 but was: System.ServiceModel.FaultException : Permissions Denied!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PermissionDenied_Error` should be a data contract. It should not be derived from Exception.

Also,you need to place the `FaultContractAttribute` on your operation contract so that the client knows to expect an exception.

**Added by Valamas**

```
public interface IAccess
{
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(PermissionDenied_Error))]
        DtoResponse Access(DtoRequest request);
}
```

Comment: I realize now that this is the correct answer. I have edited your answer so the code displays correctly.

Answer (score 2):

in WCF simply does not work like that.

there are articles around explaining how to setup and use `FaultExceptions`

check this step by step here: [Exception Handling in Windows Communication Framework and Best Practices](http://www.extremeexperts.com/Net/Articles/ExceptionHandlingInWCF.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Using the ExpectedException attribute is a bad practice. Instead of using this:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(FaultException<PermissionDenied_Error>))]
```

try doing:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    .....
    try{
       WfcServiceCall(...);
       Assert.Fail("a FaultException<PermissionDenied_Error> was expected!");
    }catch(FaultException<PermissionDenied_Error>){
       Assert.Sucess();
    }catch(Exception e){
       Assert.Fail("Unexpected exception!")
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.